# Capturing images from MIPI camera using v4l2

Tags: c, v4l2

I used the code snippet (V4L2 C API's) from the link below to capture MJPEG & YUYV images from an USB camera.

https://gist.github.com/jayrambhia/5866483

When I use the same code with an MIPI CSI camera, the code freezes and does not return an image.

Does V4L2 C API need any changes to use MIPI camera? Or is there any sample code snippet available for this (without gstreamer)?

Comment: There's no activity in that repo for a long time now.

Comment: Is a "/dev/videoX" created when you use a MIPI CSI camera?

Comment: And you're asking for an example code so... could you please take a look to this up-to-date project? https://github.com/BoubacarDiene/mmstreamer. V4L2 part can be found in https://github.com/BoubacarDiene/mmstreamer/src/video/V4l2.c

Comment: Yes, the dev/videox is created when I connect MIPI CSI camera. Itseems it is an driver issue. Even OpenCV is not able to access the camera. It throws "v4l2 bad address" error. Only gstreamer works

Comment: "Bad address" means EFAULT. It happens when an invalid address is passed to kernel.

Comment: Which ioctl command exactly fails? I unfortunately do not have a MIPI camera but here are some checks i would make: 1) Analyze output of "dmesg" command hopping to see more details there 2) Try with V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR instead of V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP